# How do I access json using reactjs from expressjs?

Tags: javascript, node.js, reactjs, express

I am new to `reactjs` and `expressjs`. How do I get the data from `reactjs` and store it in a variable.

So far I am able to do `res.send` the data.

```
app.get('*', (req, res) => {
     const data = {hello: world};
     res.send(data);
});
```

This sends the data to the browser and displays but I want to just save the data to a variable instead of displaying it.

Comment: where is your display code?

Comment: You have already stored the data to a constant, what is it that you actually want to do? What have you tried?

Comment: Are you asking how do you store variables from the client to the server ?

Comment: how do i access and display data from server to client

Answer (score 1):

You can in your React Component do something like:

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import './App.css';
class App extends Component {
   constructor(){
       super();
       this.state ={users: []};
   }
   componentDidMount() {
          fetch('/users')
            .then(users => { 
                console.log(users); 
                this.setState({ users })
             });
         }
   render() {
        return (
            <div className="App">
                <h1>Users</h1>
                {this.state.users.map(user =>
                <div key={user.id}>user: {user.name} Password: {user.password}</div>
              )}
            </div>
        );
    }
}
export default App;
```

Assuming the object you're interested in called "users"
(* You need to change your JSX according to your object fields for sure, to test this)

Answer (score 1):

This is React.js example

```
import axios from 'axios'

click () {
  axios.get('yourAPIAdress')
    .then(response => console.log(response))
}
```

and this is your node.js example code;

```
const https = require('https');

https.get('yourAPIAdress', (resp) => {
  let data = '';

  // A chunk of data has been recieved.
  resp.on('data', (chunk) => {
    data += chunk;
  });

  // The whole response has been received. Print out the result.
  resp.on('end', () => {
    console.log(JSON.parse(data).explanation);
  });

}).on("error", (err) => {
  console.log("Error: " + err.message);
});
```